# stellar withdrawal -

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellarport

I withdrew my stellar twice but it failed. Stellar charged me.  How do I get the charges back and why can't stellar transfer coins to coinspot?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Failed transactions still cost a small fee, you will be unable to get this back.

If you're using a hardware wallet I suggest making sure everything is up to date and trying again in with your browser in Icognito Mode or on another browser altogether.

Comment: Hi,  Everything is uptodate.  So what went wrong.  Will I be able to withdraw my other cryto in the wallet?  I used Brave, did this affect?

Comment: I do not have problems with other sites.  Just stellar lumen site.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment. It says your operation is underfunded. You could be trying to send too many lumens to cover the base reserve fee. For example: If you have 10 lumens in your account you will only be able to send ~9.5 and not your full balance.